# How can I know what are the automatically bins will be created?

Tags: system-verilog

This code is from "SystemVerilog IEEE STD 1800-2017 ":

```
bit [7:0] a;
covergroup ga ( int abm);
  option.auto_bin_max = abm;
  coverpoint a { ignore_bins i = {3}; }
endgroup

ga gv1 = new (64);
ga gv2 = new (32);
```

It is written that in the example above:
"In this case, the bins of the instance referenced by gv1 are “auto[0:3]” through “auto[252:255],” while the
bins of the instance referenced by gv2 are “auto[0:7]” through “auto[248:255].”"

Can someone explain it to me, why those bins are created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The option `auto_bin_max` sets the maximum number of bins that will be created automatically. So, with an 8-bit variable `a` (as you have here), instead of creating 256 bins (one bin per value), you get `auto_bin_max` bins.

When `auto_bin_max` is set to 64 for covergroup instance `gv1` (which is actually its default value anyway), so you get 64 equally-sized bins. 256/64=4, each bin is 4 values.

When `auto_bin_max` is set to 32 for covergroup instance `gv2`, so you get 32 equally-sized bins. 256/32=8, so each bin is 8 values.